# 50A 120V subpanel using 6/2+G feed

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, subpanel

Thinking of adding a 50A subpanel in my basement to shorten the runs of 6 new 120V circuits I have to run. There is an existing old range cable that is 6/2 with ground that I would be using as hot and neutral. There will not be a lot of simultaneous use on these circuits.

1. Could I just use one pole of the existing double-pole breaker for this? Or would I need a dedicated single-pole breaker?
2. Would it cause too much of an imbalance in the main panel?
3. If so, would moving some circuits to the opposite leg be a viable solution?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Good chance that 6/2 range cable is two hots with a bare neutral.  For 50 amps you want two hots a neutral and ground.  What will be on these new circuits?  Lights or something that takes more power?  Six 15 amp circuit is already 90 amps possible, closer to 72 is you go by the derate.  You probably need a load calculation for your main panel also.

Comment: Yes, it's two hots and a bare ground.  I plan to use one of the hots as a neutral.  Why do I need two hots?  I'm only running 120V circuits.  The maximum simultaneous load on this circuit could only ever be perhaps 30A and the odds of that happening are low.  I think I just answered my own question.  I can't see that causing an imbalance in the main panel.

Answer (score 2):

Don't scrimp on breaker spaces in the subpanel. Breaker spaces are dirt cheap when buying the panel, regrets are expensive.

NM 6/2 w/ground (black, white, bare) was never legal for a range connection, but is legal for a 120V subpanel.

#6 SEU (black, black, mesh ground) was legal, but that's not legal for a 120V panel because one of the wires needs to be white or gray.  If you want to choose a wire and mark it white or gray with electrical tape or shrink tube,  don't complain when the inspector nixes it.

You'll have to wire it as a 120V panel.

### If it's copper wire

#6 NM is good to 55A.  #6 SEU is good to 65A.  You can 'round up' to the next available breaker size, but cannot provision more load than the 55A (6600 watts) or 65A (7800 watts) respectively. Passing readers: remember this is a 120V panel which is why the watts are half what you'd expect.

You can't buy a 50A/120V breaker, so you'll need to use 50A/240V supply breaker and just don't use one of the terminals.  Or larger size as appropriate.

On the subpanel end, you'll need to "fork" the single hot wire to both main lugs of the panel using a VERY large wire nut, Polaris connector or other appropriate means to splice three #6.  DO NOT stick 2 wires into 1 lug, no matter how tempting it is!  In a few panels, it's possilble to shave off insulation in the right places and have the supply wire run *through* lug #1 onto lug #2.

### If it's aluminum wire

#6 NM is good for 40A.  #6 SEU is good for 50A.

However, it needs to be terminated on terminals rated for aluminum. Won't be a problem for neutral or ground, since panel lugs and breakers are rated for aluminum.

However, you will be forced into a costly Polaris splice if you try to fork the hot wire to both main lugs.   Another option is to use a short length of wire to bridge the main lugs *to each other* so it's now a 120V panel... then install a 50/60/70A breaker onto the bus as a "backfeed breaker" (you'll need a tie-down kit).  Then land your hot wire on one of the two breaker terminals - it is rated for aluminum.

Comment: All copper. The 6/2 is black/red/bare ground, and yes, I intended to tape the red as white.  Don't intend to scrimp on space, but there are always tandem breakers.  Yes, I know to pigtail the black connections to the panel.  And BTW, you certainly can get a single-pole 50A breaker.  I checked it out--Home Depot sells an Eaton BR for under $10.  But I would just leave the existing one in place and use one pole.  Unless I need the other space in the future.  Thanks very much for the info and confirming what I want to do.

Comment: @MrTrashcan1 well your #6 copper is good to 65A if it's SEU.